# Run shell command("su") for current screen View

Tags: android, shell

I am trying to execute a shell script from my Android application to get current screen view.
I have got following code working properly on rooted devices only.

```
    Process sh = null;
    try
    {
        Thread thread=new Thread(new Threadcalling ());
        thread.start();

        sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();
        os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        sh.waitFor();
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
```

What modification should I do to get screen View on non-rooted devices.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can't do that on non-rooted devices. If you could you would be able to write evil spy software.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this for non-rooted devices, in other words, you app *has* to be a *system app* to access other system apps.

**EDIT**: Maybe this link may help you: 
https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/